# Google Wave source code

Tags: google-wave

I wish to 'engineer' the google wave and try it for my blog/website ? Is it possible to tinker with the source code of Google Wave ? Where is it available ?

Has anyone done something like this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend and embed Google Wave using the [Google Wave APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/); however, Google Wave, itself, is a Google Web Toolkit application, and its source code is not available to the general public, AFAIK.

Comment: Okay ! ..... I meant exactly that .... it doesn't bother me much if it is not open sourced ..... as long as I can tailor it to my requirements !

Comment: The google wave source code is now available, the protocol specs are at http://www.waveprotocol.org and there's an apache incubating project on http://incubator.apache.org/wave

Answer (score 4):

As noted, you probably want to [embed a wave](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/embed/guide.html) in your blog, not copy the whole source.

However, if you want to set up your own wave service, [you can do that, too](http://www.waveprotocol.org/). Wave **is**, in fact, [an open protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Wave#Protocol) to encourage widespread adoption. They hope to get us all off this email thing, God bless 'em.

Comment: Reading this makes me sad. Its 10 years later and the standard is still "this email thing"...

Answer (score 1):

Google wave has not been open sourced. You can check the OS code offerd by Google here: http://code.google.com/opensource/

Comment: @Remo.D : Wikipedia says that it is open sourced, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_wave#Open_source

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what Google says. The only trace of Wave is the "Google Wave Federation Protocol" (http://code.google.com/p/wave-protocol/).

Answer (score 1):

The [Google Wave API](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/) is available from Google Labs.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is open source, available through the "wave-protocol" link. In fact, here is a walkthrough of the codebase:
http://www.waveprotocol.org/code/wave-model-code-walk

Answer (score 1):

There is an open-source implementation of the Wave Gadget API you can use with other sites; it uses Node.js:

https://github.com/scottbw/wave-node

Answer (score 0):

Google Wave's source code isn't open source, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Search the Google API for that.

I believe you can incorporate the wave on your site.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Wave protocol is here :

http://www.waveprotocol.org/code

And now it is being moved to Apache :

https://incubator.apache.org/wave/about.html